# ViewPager in simple Dialog

Tags: android, dialog, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I would like to use a ViewPager in a dialog but fail epicly! Here is all the code. There is two fragments to be shown in the dialog:

## Layouts

**main.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".Main" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="dialog" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**details.xml** (Fragment layout)

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/detailsText"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dip"
    android:text="Large Text"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:textSize="30dip" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**image.xml** (Fragment layout)

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**dialog.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1" />

<com.viewpagerindicator.CirclePageIndicator
    android:id="@+id/indicator"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="10dip" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**Main.java**

```
public class Main extends FragmentActivity {

private Button button;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    setupUIComponents();
    setupListeners();
}

private void setupUIComponents() {
    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
}

private void setupListeners() {
    button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            MyDialog dialog = new MyDialog(Main.this);
            dialog.startDialog();
        }
    });
}
}
```

**MyDialog.java**

```
public class MyDialog extends FragmentActivity {

private Dialog dialog;
private Context context;
private CirclePageIndicator mIndicator;
private Main mMain;
private ViewPager mPager;
private FragmentAdapter mAdapter;

public MyDialog(Context context) {
    super();
    this.context = context;
    this.mMain = (Main) context;
}

public void startDialog() {
    dialog = new Dialog(context);
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog);

    mAdapter = new FragmentAdapter(mMain.getSupportFragmentManager());
    mPager = (ViewPager) dialog.findViewById(R.id.pager);
    mPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);

    mIndicator = (CirclePageIndicator) dialog.findViewById(R.id.indicator);
    mIndicator.setViewPager(mPager);
    mIndicator.setCurrentItem(0);

    dialog.show();
}

}
```

**FragmentAdapter.java**

```
public class FragmentAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
public FragmentAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
    super(fm);
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int which) {
    switch (which) {
        case 0:
            ImageFragment imageFragment = new ImageFragment();
            return imageFragment;
        case 1:
            DetailFragment detailsFragment = new DetailFragment();
            return detailsFragment;
    }
    return null;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return 2;
}

}
```

**DetailsFragment.java**

```
public class DetailFragment extends Fragment {
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.details, container, false);
    TextView textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.detailsText);
    textView.setText("Testing");
    return view;
}
}
```

**ImageFragment.java**

```
public class ImageFragment extends Fragment {

public ImageFragment() {
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.image, container, false);
    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    imageView.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_launcher));
    return view;
}
}
```

To sum the code up quickly, Main.java is started, clicking on the button shall fire up a dialog with two fragments in a view pager.

**There is the stacktrace:**

```
12-11 11:28:15.999: E/AndroidRuntime(7453): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-11 11:28:15.999: E/AndroidRuntime(7453): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f040006 for fragment ImageFragment{410a2468 #0 id=0x7f040006 android:switcher:2130968582:0}
12-11 11:28:15.999: E/AndroidRuntime(7453):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:864)
12-11 11:28:15.999: E/AndroidRuntime(7453):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1080)
12-11 11:28:15.999: E/AndroidRuntime(7453):     at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:622)
12-11 11:28:15.999: E/AndroidRuntime(7453):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1416)
12-11 11:28:15.999: E/AndroidRuntime(7453):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executePendingTransactions(FragmentManager.java:431)
12-11 11:28:15.999: E/AndroidRuntime(7453):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentPagerAdapter.java:139)
12-11 11:28:15.999: E/AndroidRuntime(7453):     at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:804)
12-11 11:28:15.999: E/AndroidRuntime(7453):     at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1016)
12-11 11:28:15.999: E/AndroidRuntime(7453):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15172)
12-11 11:28:15.999: E/AndroidRuntime(7453):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4816)
12-11 11:28:15.999: E/AndroidRuntime(7453):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1390)
12-11 11:28:15.999: E/AndroidRuntime(7453):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:681)
12-11 11:28:15.999: E/AndroidRuntime(7453):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:574)
12-11 11:28:15.999: E/AndroidRuntime(7453):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15172)
12-11 11:28:15.999: E/AndroidRuntime(7453):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4816)
12-11 11:28:15.999: E/AndroidRuntime(7453):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
12-11 11:28:15.999: E/AndroidRuntime(7453):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15172)
12-11 11:28:15.999: E/AndroidRuntime(7453):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4816)
12-11 11:28:15.999: E/AndroidRuntime(7453):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
12-11 11:28:15.999: E/AndroidRuntime(7453):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15172)
12-11 11:28:15.999: E/AndroidRuntime(7453):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4816)
12-11 11:28:15.999: E/AndroidRuntime(7453):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1390)
12-11 11:28:15.999: E/AndroidRuntime(7453):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:681)
12-11 11:28:15.999: E/AndroidRuntime(7453):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:574)
12-11 11:28:15.999: E/AndroidRuntime(7453):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15172)
12-11 11:28:15.999: E/AndroidRuntime(7453):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4816)
12-11 11:28:15.999: E/AndroidRuntime(7453):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
12-11 11:28:15.999: E/AndroidRuntime(7453):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2148)
12-11 11:28:15.999: E/AndroidRuntime(7453):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15172)
12-11 11:28:15.999: E/AndroidRuntime(7453):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:1850)
12-11 11:28:15.999: E/AndroidRuntime(7453):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1077)
12-11 11:28:15.999: E/AndroidRuntime(7453):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1275)
12-11 11:28:15.999: E/AndroidRuntime(7453):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1000)
12-11 11:28:15.999: E/AndroidRuntime(7453):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:4214)
12-11 11:28:15.999: E/AndroidRuntime(7453):     at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:725)
12-11 11:28:15.999: E/AndroidRuntime(7453):     at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:555)
12-11 11:28:15.999: E/AndroidRuntime(7453):     at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:525)
12-11 11:28:15.999: E/AndroidRuntime(7453):     at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:711)
12-11 11:28:15.999: E/AndroidRuntime(7453):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
12-11 11:28:15.999: E/AndroidRuntime(7453):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
12-11 11:28:15.999: E/AndroidRuntime(7453):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
12-11 11:28:15.999: E/AndroidRuntime(7453):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4966)
12-11 11:28:15.999: E/AndroidRuntime(7453):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-11 11:28:15.999: E/AndroidRuntime(7453):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
12-11 11:28:15.999: E/AndroidRuntime(7453):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:791)
12-11 11:28:15.999: E/AndroidRuntime(7453):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:558)
12-11 11:28:15.999: E/AndroidRuntime(7453):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Again, is it possible to show fragments in a viewpager in a dialog? And if so, where abouts did I go wrong?

Comment: Do you have any other code missed out from your project?

Comment: No. Of course I'm using the support package in order to be able to use the viewpager because it's not provided in the "normal" Android SDK. Other than that this is all code of my project. I have to admit though that I did not post any pictures like R.drawable.ic_launcer which I'm using but I find it quite fascinating that you asked me this question in less than a minute after I posted this question! I would love to be able to read so many lines of code so quickly as you obviously can!

Comment: Kindly go through video for View Pager in Dialog **https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pJG5ZuZtPKY**

Answer (score 4):

> Again, is it possible to show fragments in a viewpager in a dialog?

Yes, but not the way you tried(if I'm not missing something in your code), the `ViewPager` will not be able to attach those child `Fragments` as it's placed in the dialog. The `4.2` API level brought [nested Fragments](http://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-4.2.html#NestedFragments)(but also available on lower versions with the new versions of the compatibility package) which you should use to show your "in dialog fragments".

In your `Main` activity you would create a `DialogFragment` and in that `DialogFragment` you would setup the `ViewPager` and pass `getChildFragmentManager()` to its adapter.

Also, just use move the `startDialog()` method in the `Main` activity and **don't** instantiate a new `Activity` as that is not the way Android goes(in your case it works because you're not doing anything with it).

Comment: Kindly go through video for View Pager in Dialog for future references **https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pJG5ZuZtPKY**. It will help lots of people.